# Reading in very large excel file in Python ( using pandas) about 500,000 rows

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner in python and trying to read a very large excel file ( about 500,000 rows and 10 columns) 
I'm using the following syntax :

```
import pandas as pd

vendor_data = pd.read_excel('vendor_data.xlsx')
```

it is taking forever , 
is there a faster way to do this.
Could anyone provide the syntax also on how to do this?

Comment: How are you running this?  In an IDE?

Comment: No way round this one, in all likelihood. Excel is notoriously slow. I recommend you convert to CSV / HDF5 / Pickle.

Comment: Im using VScode